# Creating a 3D bar overlay on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, 3d, visualization, data-visualization

I have been trying to find a way to create 3D bars on top of google map along the lines of a road representing some parameters related to road condition. 
I m trying to achieve something like this but on google maps instead.
[image]

I tried to look for available charting libraries. The closest one I could get to is [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/3d-hexbin/) , using the hexbins [image: Exploring NYC Open Data with 3D hexbins]

However, it is not flexible enough to include my own user interactions and control.

Another impressive demo that I came across is [this](http://www.xibis.com/blogposts/xibis-map-graph) from Xibis. However it is just a sample and I couldn't figure out how it is done.
[image]

Are there any such libraries available or any ideas to achieve something similar?

Comment: It might be worth having a look at https://github.com/UDST/vizicities also. I suspect it doesn't do exactly what you are after, but it does handle visual representations of data pretty well